# Vector fields on a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-fields, spheres

I am interested in what smooth vector fields on spheres look like. I am aware of the hairy ball theorem prohibiting the existence of nowhere vanishing smooth vector fields on a sphere, but I would like to permit zeros of the vector field. Are there any theorems on the number of zeros are allowed? Ultimately I would like to be able to write down the general form of a smooth vector field as a sum of basis functions (much like sines and cosines provide a basis for piecewise continuous functions on an interval). Any help e.g. answers with explanations or relevant references would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can get away with a single zero, as witnessed by [this image from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem#/media/File:Hairy_ball_one_pole.jpg).

Comment: Here's a guess:  On $S^n$, the vector fields generated by rotation in the " principal axes of an $n$-sphere give a family of $n+1$ vector fields which span all of them as a $C^\infty(S^n)$ module.  E.g., for $S^2$, the three vector fields given by rotating around the $x$,$y$, and $z$-axis respectively span (as a $C^\infty(S^2)$-module) all the vector fields

Comment: Spheres are symmetric spaces, so to understand vector fields on $\mathbb{S}^n$, understand $SO(n)$-invariant vector fields on $SO(n+1)$. (I think this is a different way of phrasing what @JasonDeVito suggested.

Comment: Another approach could be to use the standard embedding and write a vector field as an $(n+1)$-tuple of maps $\mathbb{S}^n\to \mathbb{R}$, then expand in spherical harmonics.